# ambiguousruleexception in snakemake, parms crash of two branches

Tags: snakemake

I have two classes of samples to be processed by different params in my first run, then merge them together in second run. like the following example:

```
SAMPLES = ['1', '2', '3']
CLASS1 = ['1', '2']
CLASS2 = ['3']

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{class1}.first.txt', class1 = CLASS1),
        expand('{class2}.first.txt', class2 = CLASS2),
        expand('{sample}.second.tx', sample = SAMPLES)

rule first_CLASS1:
    input:
        '{class1}.txt'
    output:
        '{class1}.first.txt'
    shell:
        'touch {wildcards.class1}.first.txt'

rule first_CLASS2:
    input:
        '{class2}.txt'
    output:
        '{class2}.first.txt'
    shell:
        'touch {wildcards.class2}.first.txt'

rule second:
    input:
        '{sample}.first.txt'
    output:
        '{sample}.second.txt'
    shell:
        'touch {wildcards.sample}.second.txt'
```

but I got the AmbiguousRuleException like this:

```
AmbiguousRuleException:
Rules first_CLASS2 and first_CLASS1 are ambiguous for the file 1.first.txt.
Consider starting rule output with a unique prefix, constrain your wildcards, or use the ruleorder directive.
Wildcards:
    first_CLASS2: class2=1
    first_CLASS1: class1=1
Expected input files:
    first_CLASS2: 1.txt
    first_CLASS1: 1.txtExpected output files:
    first_CLASS2: 1.first.txt
    first_CLASS1: 1.first.txt
```

I declared

```
expand('{class2}.first.txt', class2 = CLASS2)
```

in run all, and `CLASS2 = ['3']`. 
However it reported `class2 = 1`, which really made me confused.

Comment: sorry, '{sample}.escond.txt' stands for '{sample}.second.txt'

Comment: You can fix your typos using the "edit" link (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56122204/edit). (I did it for you for the escond -> second)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because `{class1}.first.txt` and `{class2}.first.txt` share the same constant part, i.e. `.first.txt` and as the error message suggests they are not unique. You can resolve it by constraining the wildcards by putting before the rule all:

```
wildcard_constraints:
    class1= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in CLASS1]),
    class2= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in CLASS2]),
```

See also this question of mine at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/snakemake/wVlJW9X-9EU/gSZh4U0_CQAJ. Personally I would prefer if the constraints were the default behaviour...

Comment: As far as I understand, wildcard names are "rule-scoped". Snakemake tries to match requested inputs with possible outputs. Then, it infers the values to give to the wildcards by matching the "concrete" input name of a rule instance (for instance `"3.first.txt"`) with the (possibly wildcarded) output name of a rule (`"{class1}.first.txt"` and `"{class2}.first.txt"`). The fact that `"3"` in `"3.first.txt"` came from `class2` in rule `all` is "forgotten" when the matches are performed.

Comment: Thank you dariober and bli. Your answers are really helpful. Better understanding on snakemake wildcard! Here is the introduction of wildcard constraints in snakemake. Hope this help others. [Rules](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html)